# Entity Framework Timeout Expired

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1, timeout

I recently publish my ASP.Net MVC 3 web application (Entity Framework 4.1 for Data Persistence) to a live server. The application is located on one web server and the database (SQL Server 2008) is located on another separate server.

The site has only been live a few days with very few hits, and because of this there are very few records contained within the database tables (10- 20 max).

I also have ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers for ASP.NET) integrated into the site and I have received a few instances of the following error already

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding.

Below shows the full details as supplied by ELMAH

> System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, UInt32 error)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean
>   encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean& marsCapable)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginWithFailover(Boolean
>   useFailoverHost, ServerInfo primaryServerInfo, String failoverHost,
>   String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer
>   timeout)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) 
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
>   Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
>   Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)    at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)

The occasions where this error has happened have been due to SELECT queries. These select queries are very simple, ie,

> Select  col1, col2, col3 from table where col1 = 1

And as I have stated, there is very little data within the database, so it isn’t as if the queries are pulling back 100’s of records.

I have done some research into this using both the **Internet** and **Stackoverflow**. Some people suggest to increase the **dbContext CommandTimeout** Property, however, I don’t understand why I should need to do this. Yes, if I were pulling back loads of records, but as I have said, these are simple **SELECT** statements pulling back 1-5 records at the most.

I also know that developers need to keep an eye on the SQL generated by the Entity Framework, so, I downloaded and ran this trial version http://www.datawizard.com in order to get a look at the SQL being created for the Entity Framework SELECT queries that were causing a problem. Again, the profiler showed these queries to be very simple syntax, so I don’t think that is the problem.

I am beginning to think maybe it has something to do with my database and web application being on separate servers, however, I am out of ideas!

Please if anyone can help or advise me with this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Do you have a DbContext Initializer set up in production? It isn't trying to run your Seed method, is it?

Comment: @danludwig Although I am using EF 4.1 and the dbContext, I am using the Database First approach, not the Code First. So far as I know, there is no DbContext Initializer.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: From the stack trace, this is a connection timeout, not a command timeout. Something is preventing new connections from connecting to the database. Possibly a network issue or a SQL Server configuration issue. You may have more luck asking at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). To increase the timeout period, add something like `Connect Timeout=30` to your connection string.

Comment: @Brice Sorry one other thing. How can you tell from the Stack Trace that it is a Connection Timeout, and not a Command Timeout? Thanks.

Comment: @tgriffiths, it goes through `SqlConnection.Open()` and not `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`. Also, I'm on the EF team. ;)